# I need a script that detects when there is activity on port 443

Tags: linux, scripting, webserver

I am running Wordpress and NextCloud with Nginx on port 443 on my Webserver. I have it set up so that Wordpress is the dedicated homepage and it will ALWAYS load before NextCloud.

ISSUE: Wordpress does NOT use an external hard drive and loads within 3 seconds (the webserver is not the problem). However, Nextcloud DOES use an external hard drive and it requires to spin up the hard drive before you can log in (takes 15 seconds at least).

I WOULD LIKE TO: Make a script that to detects activity on port 443, so when someone accesses Wordpress (the homepage) the server can get a head start by spinning up the drive

How do I make a script that can detect activity on 443 and spin up the drive?

Comment: How is your script going to be any faster than a webserver?

Comment: I think you got a `-1` because it is an unsolvable problem. Try this: Wait for the harddisk to spin down. Then run the command on your site `curl -I http://example.org/`. If this takes a long time, there is no way you can be ahead of spinning up the drive.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than trying to spin the drive up in time for handling an incoming request (you can't do this faster than the web server anyway), don't allow the drive to spin down.

This can be done in a number of different ways.  On Linux, you may want to try the `hdparm` utility (for SATA and IDE drives):

```
$ hdparm -B 128 device_name
```

Be sure to read the manual properly before using this utility.

See also relevant questions on the Ask Ubuntu site (answers are not specific to Ubuntu):

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/39760/how-can-i-control-hdd-spin-down-time
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/891173/disable-spinning-down-of-hdd-in-16-04

Comment: @TylerDeBoy Actually, stopping and starting the drive constantly will wear it out, not having it on 24/7. The only real reason to spin it down is for power reasons.

Comment: @TylerDeBoy What kind of drive is this? I would be surprised if the drive wore out during its warranty period.